LLVM linker does not work on MacOS while trying to develop on-chain Solana app (C++)
this is the error i get:
./account_logger.so ()
dyld[61282]: Library not loaded: @rpath/libLLVM.dylib
  Referenced from: <A9E4BE2A-BF8D-3956-BCA9-E3BC5A6C9F9C> /Users/myusername/.local/share/solana/install/releases/stable-6c6442ff1444dc4404b1de5cb3ffc6fa48e8a73d/solana-release/bin/sdk/sbf/dependencies/platform-tools/llvm/bin/ld.lld
  Reason: tried: '/Users/myusername/.local/share/solana/install/releases/stable-6c6442ff1444dc4404b1de5cb3ffc6fa48e8a73d/solana-release/bin/sdk/sbf/dependencies/platform-tools/llvm/bin/../lib/libLLVM.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/myusername/.local/share/solana/install/releases/stable-6c6442ff1444dc4404b1de5cb3ffc6fa48e8a73d/solana-release/bin/sdk/sbf/dependencies/platform-tools/llvm/bin/../lib/libLLVM.dylib' (no such file)
make: *** [account_logger.so] Abort trap: 6

I tried reinstalling LLVM several times and with multiple methods and it still didn't work. I'm on macOS.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I have the same problem but using WSL2 (Linux)...
I figured out a temporary fix:
The problem was the path ~/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.18.17/solana-release/bin/sdk/sbf/dependencies/platform-tools/llvm/bin/llvm-readelf which is a symlink to ~/.cache/solana/v1.41/platform-tools/llvm/bin/llvm-readelf which is again a symlink to~/.cache/solana/v1.41/platform-tools/llvm/bin/llvm-readobj, file which I didn't have.
However, I had it under /usr/bin/llvm-readobj, so I just did cp /usr/bin/llvm-readobj ~/.cache/solana/v1.41/platform-tools/llvm/bin/llvm-readobj and the problem was fixed.
